# Why are dynamically created labels not showing correctly?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Okay, for some reason this won't work, but I've done it before.

I'm creating a hangman application, and my dynamic labels simply won't show up.

I wrote this code:

```
Dim xLabel As Integer = lblPosition.Location.X
Dim yLabel As Integer = lblPosition.Location.Y
For i As Integer = 0 To film.Length - 1
    Dim label1 As New Label
    xLabel += 20
    label1.Location = New Point(xLabel, yLabel)
    label1.Text = "_"
    label1.Font = New Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", _
                  16, _
                  FontStyle.Bold)
    label1.ForeColor() = Color.White
    label1.Name = "lblLetter" & i
    Me.Controls.Add(label1)
Next
```

So a label is created for every character in the `film` string, with an underscore as the text. `lblPosition` is the label on which I base the other label's position.

The labels don't show up. I can change the underscore to something long, and it will just show the last character.

My form is certainly wide enough and I have no label called `label1` yet.
It compiles as well.

EDIT: This is what the labels look like if I add a border, still no text though.

[image]

EDIT 2: The font size is the same as the first underscore, if I use letters, I get this (the font size is also reduced)

[image]

Comment: they likely are being added.  the font is large so the size may not be tall enough and they could very well be overlapped resulting in just the last character showing up.  set borderstyle to 3D and see what else is wrong.

Comment: *that font is large, so the size may not be tall enough* - the underscore (`_`) will be way at the bottom, likely outside the border.  Set a specific size large enough to show...just put a letter or 2 in there and you'll see how they are clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `label1.AutoSize = True` into your loop:

```
Dim xLabel As Integer = lblPosition.Location.X
Dim yLabel As Integer = lblPosition.Location.Y
For i As Integer = 0 To film.Length - 1
    Dim label1 As New Label
    xLabel += 25 ' <---- 25 works better with your font size
    label1.Location = New Point(xLabel, yLabel)
    label1.AutoSize = True ' <---- HERE!
    label1.Text = "_"
    label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle ' <---- Added border for demo
    label1.Font = New Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", _
                  16, _
                  FontStyle.Bold)
    label1.ForeColor() = Color.White
    label1.Name = "lblLetter" & i
    Me.Controls.Add(label1)
Next
```

Without `AutoSize`:

[image]

With `AutoSize`:

[image]

Comment: Or if you don't want auto sizing but fixed size you can just set `label1.Size`.